# Calculated column with multiple options depending on start date of event compared to today

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm attempting to create a column ("30, 60, 90, +") that reports if an entry is within 30, 60, or 90 days out. 
One field is "Start Date" and I want the field to report '30' if the start date is within 30 days from today, '60' between 31-60 days from today, and '90' for between 61-90; with '+' being the entry beyond that timeframe.
Is this doable?

Comment: Hi Dustin, welcome to the [SharePoint S.E.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)! One thing you'll need to keep in mind is that typically SharePoint list items won't update on a regular basis. They only update when you either trigger a save on the list item, or you modify the field. So in this case, if you create a column that calculates 30/60/90/+ days out, it won't tick town from +, to 90, to 60, then to 30. It'll only change when you A) create the item, or B) cause a save event to trigger.

Comment: That makes sense...thank you @KGlasier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot configure a calculated field as you described since calculated fields update their values on updating list items. Thus, the formula cannot include variables other than fields. You can configure a Flow of Workflow that updates a field value periodically in the beginning of each day.